# regex match doesn't seem to work javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a regex.exec() function like this:

```
var chat = reader.result;
var regex = /(\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{2,4}) (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d): ([^:]+): (.*)/g;
var messages = [];

var match;
while( match = regex.exec(chat)) {
        messages.push({
            date: match[1],
            time: match[2],
            name: match[3],
            message: match[4]
    });
}
```

match[1] seems to work on almost all dates: dd/mm/yyyy to dd-mm-yy

However, when the input is in the following format:

```
22-2-2014 18:37:15: Andre: Moet nog 2,5 aflevering
```

it outputs an empty array `messages`

I don't really know where this is coming from but I believe it's regex `match[1]`, because when the input is `28/02/14 00:03:03: Tom: Je gaat nu de afweging maken`

It returns an array of objects just fine.

P.s. for the ones interested, the reader.result is from the HTML5 filereader API.

**EDIT** I've updated the question with a bug in the regex that was found by a commenter. Still, even with the newer regex the input still fails

Comment: The month portion of your date is only one digit.  It if failing there.

Comment: Also, [this is a great site that I love using](http://regexpal.com/), I recommend you check it out for things like this.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried a new regex for match[1]: (\d\d[\/-]\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{2,4}) but it still fails on the problematic input..

Comment: @user3263723 Please don't delete this question when you find the answer; then it becomes useless to future visitors with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex ([see demo link](http://regex101.com/r/wG6cM6))

```
 (\d\d[\/-]\d\d?[\/-]\d{2,4}) (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d): ([^:]+): (.*)
```

it matches both:

> 22-2-2014 18:37:15: Andre: Moet nog 2,5 aflevering
>
> 22-12-2014 18:37:15: Andre: Moet nog 2,5 aflevering

Comment: Thanks! That worked :) could you share how you found d\d? working instead of d{1,2}?

Comment: `\d\d?`  will match one digit and optional 2nd digit. `d{1,2}?` will match one or two digits, but due to `?` just optionally

Comment: so `\d\d?` matches the same like `d{1,2}` and `\d?\d?` matches the same like `d{1,2}?`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your regex misses the exception for a single digit month.
try this:

```
/(\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{2,4}) (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d): ([^:]+): (.*)/g
```

edit: also built in optional single digit days.

Comment: Thanks. It indeed does seem like it and I'm sure it's a bug in the regex but it isn't the solution to the error, unfortunately.